# ubuntu 14.04 LTS won't boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, gnu

just a few days ago i purchased a dell inspiron laptop with pre-installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS. i was installing the software center and updating in the software updater and it was just completed upto 85% and then  it's just goes unresponsive . after this i tried to shutdown but it won't so i just forcefully shutdowned using the power button.when i restarted it's showing a black screen and it's showing the following-

```
            GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3
```

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.for the first word,TAB 
 lists possible completion. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
device or file completion.

grub>_

please help me to step forward!

Answer (score 1):

**Find root partition**

You must know what's your root partition to boot Ubuntu. Try:

```
ls
```

Now you can see some disks and partitions. You must list each partition to find where ubuntu is installed. For example:

```
ls (hd0,gpt3)
```

If this is your root partition, you can see the directories boot, dev, etc, usr,... When you find it:

```
set root=(hd0,gptX)
```

where *gptX* is your root partition.

**Launching ubuntu**

Find your kernel image with:

```
ls /boot
```

You can see one or more images with names like *vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic*. Now load the last image with:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1
```

And

```
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
```

Now you can boot into ubuntu with

```
boot
```

**Restore grub**

Once in ubuntu, open terminal and write

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Don't forget update before restart with :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Also, you can use a graphic repair tool like Boot Repair.

I hope this help you.