# GNU GRUB problem after ubuntu 16.04 update

Tags: grub2, gnu

After downloading and installing the automatic updates for ubuntu 16.04, my system crashed. Whenever I boot the computer, a bash screen appears with the header GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16. Obviously, the kernel cannot be accessed. Tab delivers a variety of possible commands, but unfortunately I don't know which one to use. I run ubuntu on a Lenovo Yoga machine. It would be great if anyone could help me! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Same here. I ended up fixing it using recovery CD to repair grub related stuff. You can take look at this one https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: After repair you may encounter problems using Ubuntu 16.04 on the newly updated Kernel `4.13.0-xx`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ls
```

And you will see, for example:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos2) (hd1,msdos1)
```

Now you can see some disks and partitions. You must list each partition to find where ubuntu is installed. For example:

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub 
set root=(hd0,1)
```

With these commands, we specify to use the disk (hd0,1) for further commands. After that, you need to check whether there really is on this section what we need. We give the command:

```
ls /boot/grub
```

if the answer is a list of all the files in this directory, then the disk and partition are selected correctly. We load modules:

```
insmod ext2
insmod normal
normal
```

If everything is ok and working, next step - restore grub in Linux terminal

P.S. I founded this method [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/673348/795754) and [here](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub) :-)

Comment: Thanks! However, when I type ls, I get the output "Secure Boot forbids loading module from (hd0, gpt2)/boot/grub/x86-64-efi/ls.mod." So I cannot access or change the directory... is there a trick I can apply here?

Comment: I got it working! I just had to disable the secure boot option in the BIOS menu first. You can start it by pressing F2 directly after starting your computer. Just if anyone finds this forum entry and wants to apply it! Thanks again for your help, @Bellerofontessa !